# Android tcp vs udp for video streaming

Tags: java, android, networking, tcp, udp

I want to transmit live video from my phone camera to multiple users RELIABLY over network and some client specific data but with BANDWIDTH efficiency

Using tcp will ensure reliability but will need n no of connections for n no of users also the application would then have to transmit the same data over and over to all connected clients, now that would consume bandwidth as well as processing power but will allow exclusive access  to each connection like disconnecting or reconnecting a client or sending client specific data etc

On the other hand is udp that can save some bandwidth because copying data would be handled by router etc. but it is said to be unreliable and I dont think it would allow exclusive control for each client like tcp does (correct me if i'm wrong)

So which approach should I use?

EDIT:

Data and video sent would using custom methods (basically writing video frames etc to a socket output stream)

Comment: How "reliable" does "reliably" mean? Which codec are you planning to use?

Comment: See the edit section I will be sending frames manually as raw image data

Comment: Have you already done some research on the "streaming" part? The last time I had to deal with this, Android wouldn't give you streaming-ready output. If you are not using plain mjpeg it is not *that* easy as sending frames to a socket.

Comment: I'll put it differently: "Raw image data" means - each frame is independent of the other and encodes a whole picture that can be displayed in a client, correct? In that case I'd use UDP. But it does not guarantee that the clinets receive what you send. So you'll have to be a little more precise on how reliable you want it to be to give decent advice.

Comment: Yash that's what I am thinking sending frames individually . Its pretty much self evident that to give a reliable  video connection they must be received in order so as to form chronologically correct video. How unreliable can a udp multicast be?

Comment: Well, UDP won't give you "in-order". You will have to deal with this yourself. But that's no rocket science. How unreliable UDP is depends heavily on the infrastructure and its usage. But just think of Multiplayer games: They use UDP, so it can't be totally useless ;)

Comment: Right ! One more query : in udp the packets may arrive out of order so how do I get hold of them individually and put them in order because you know you may not get access to individual packets

Comment: Usually, you'll add a "Sequence" counter to your packets. It is steadily increasing, so you can "sort" them to be in order. For detecting packet loss, you'll have to implement some timeout - mechanism and then handle it. In your case, it may be sensible to ignore this and discard the whole frame (at least as a first step).

Comment: What? I thought packets were handled by networking and data link layer how would you get packets from an input stream?

Comment: I'm sorry. I used the wrong term. Of course you add a sequence counter to the user data, not the "Packet" as such.